# Oracle 11g - Create X Instances, for testing

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

We have a production issue involving multiple instances on a hosted environment.  I'd like to do some testing locally and wanted to reproduce a similar environment locally.  Is there a way to create, say 40 instances, create a simple table, populate it with a loop?

Seems like making 40 or so would take a lot of time.  Ideally, create Instance1, Instance2 and so forth, doesn't matter what the table is and wanted to put in a good amount of data to simulate some kind of processing.

Thanks

Comment: are you familiar with how Oracle works? (Instance/Database/Schema/Table)

Comment: Pretty much no, learning as I go.  I come from a SQL Server background.

Comment: ok, I had that id from your description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure if this exactly answers your question but I will give it a try.

Oracle has a database, this is a collection of datafiles. An Instance is just the collection of processes that serves as an interface to the database, for the clients. So my assumption is that you want to make schema's in the database and polulate them with tables and put some data in those tables.
if that is the case, it is quite simpel:

assume default tablepace for users is USERS
logon as dba and run

```
begin
 for i in 1..40 loop
    execute immediate 'create user schema_'||i||' identified by bigsecret quota unlimited on users';
    execute immediate 'create table schema_'||i||'.z as select * from dba_tables';
  end loop;
end;
/
```

this creates 40 schemas in a loop, named SCHEMA_1 ... SCHEMA_40.
In every schema, one table named Z is created as a copy of DBA_TABLES.
cleanup with

```
begin
 for i in 1..4 loop
    execute immediate 'drop user schema_'||i||' cascade';
  end loop;
end;
/
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I think this was the path I was looking at.  I'm using Oracle SQL Developer and basically cloned a local user and copy/pasted that SQL output and am concatenating this basically the same way.